# SQL Server - Short circuit Select Union if any returns row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do have multiple select queries which I wanted to execute against SQL server to perform some data validation.

```
Select top 1 1 from tbl1 where somecondition = 1
UNION
Select top 1 1 from tbl2 where somecondition = 1
UNION
Select top 1 1 from tbl3 where somecondition = 1
```

And what I want is if any of these three select statement returns any record then the data validation should fail. One way is to just run them sequentially and check the results. But, to make it more performant what I am thinking is to apply UNION operator so that these queries can run in parallel and short circuit some way if any returns any row. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `IF/CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... UNION ALL ... UNION ALL ...)` will give the optimizer the best chance of parallelizing and stopping early. It is of course not *guaranteed*; the whole point of SQL is that you're specifying the "what" and not the "how" to such a degree.

Comment: If you use an `EXISTS` for each instead, and have the column `somecondition` indexed, then this should be pretty performant.

Comment: "Short circuit" generally means "don't perform later operations if a condition is met", which would contradict "in parallel", because you can't decide not to do something that's already happening.

Comment: And lastly - lean when to use `UNION` vs `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @IMSoP you are right.. I quite not able to find the right word for this and that's why put short circuit. I guess the correct word might be "early return". And to achieve parallelism the way how I can achieve in code is to issue those 4 select statements individually in async manner and aborting the query as soon as I get the desired result. But that this something which I was trying to do in sql proc rather than in c#.

Answer (score 3):

`UNION` won't short-circuit.  I would suggest something more like this:

```
select v.*
from (values (1)) v(x)
where exists (select 1 from tbl1 where somecondition = 1) or
      exists (select 1 from tbl2 where somecondition = 1) or
      exists (select 1 from tbl3 where somecondition = 1) ;
```

`exists` should short-circuit evaluation if any row is found.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to fine-tune *how* and *when* a DBMS does something is generally the wrong mindset. Instead, you should try to describe the *result* you want, in a way that the DBMS itself has a chance to optimise it.

You can then test to see if it achieves the performance you were hoping for *in a specific scenario*. DBMS optimisers are incredibly complex, so that you generally can't look at a query on its own and say how the DBMS will run it - the strategy used will change depending on not just the schema but the actual data involved.

So, here is my attempt to reframe your requirement:

> I want to check if any one of three select queries will return at least one row. I don't need to know the result, or which query has the row.

The simplest way to express that in SQL is with `EXISTS` and `OR`; to make a standalone query, we can wrap in `CASE WHEN ... END`:

```sql
SELECT CASE 
   WHEN 
      EXISTS( Select 1 from tbl1 where somecondition = 1 )
      OR
      EXISTS( Select 1 from tbl2 where somecondition = 1 )
      OR
      EXISTS( Select 1 from tbl3 where somecondition = 1 )
   THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
END AS MatchExists
```

Note that I've removed the `TOP 1` from the queries - stopping when you find one matching row is already implied by `EXISTS`.

Now, I've no idea what the DBMS will do with this query. It might:

- Run the three queries sequentially, in the order specified, stopping if it finds a match.
- Spawn multiple threads each checking a condition, and abort if one finds a match, as you hoped.
- Notice from its statistics that `tbl2` has only ~10 rows, and scan that table first.
- Notice that the condition on `tbl3` can be read from an index, so check that one first.
- Some other clever trick that hasn't occurred to either of us.
- Some combination of the above.

The only way to find out is to run it *with your real data* and look at the query plan, and the measured performance. If it picks a bad approach, you may need to do something different - but that may just be updating statistics, or adding the right indexes, as with an query optimisation.